Starting docker container as service on Ubuntu vs. docker restart policy
I usually start my docker containers on my Ubuntu server by creating a service and running the docker run- command there, which I crafted and verified in the Terminal first.
However, since 2 days, I run into issues. systemctl shows problems running docker run - commands, which run without any issues when I run them directly in the terminal. There is no specific error in the service's logs, it always boils down to log entries like this:
ABC.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Stopped ABC.
ABC.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
ABC.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Failed to start ABC.

I do not really have an idea why this happens, but it happens in several docker containers which are unrelated and started as service. The corresponding docker-run-command does run fine in terminal directly. Also, I have some other docker-based services running, which all continue to work just fine.

Did anybody experience a simiar issue or could point me into the right direction for searching the root cause? Searching on s/o yields ie. this post, which is still uncommented (Docker run vs docker service - automatic container restart)
The main reason why I use a service is that I want the containers to be restarted after a reboot. However, couldn't I just use --restart always when executing the docker-run command to achieve the same functionality? Is there a reason why that would be a bad idea?


Are you sure you want to troubleshoot the issue, not just start using Docker Compose? It never failed for me if properly used.

"Start limit hit" indicates you have not searched far enough back in the logs to debug the issue.
